# Add iTextSharp reference to VB.Net project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, itext

I want to use `itextsharp` in my VB.Net project to show data in a PDF file, but I am not able to add it to my project. If I try to add a reference I see this error:

> hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component uipath

How can I get this working?

Comment: Are you saying that VS generates that error when you are adding the reference or your application generates it when you run it? We shouldn't have to ask but tell us EXACTLY what you're doing to cause that. Vague descriptions are not good enough. Are you adding it as a NuGet package?

Comment: i cant install package itextsharp as a nuget package yes

Comment: this error after executing this command Install-Package iTextSharp

Comment: Firstly, should you be using the iTextSharp package at all, given that it has been deprecated and all the documentation for the package suggests using itext7 instead?, Secondly, what type of project is it and what version of .NET is it targeting? Although it still installed for me, iTextSharp is not supported on .NET Core, which includes .NET 5.0. itext7 does appear to be compatible with .NET 5.0 at least.